# Convert an Excel file to a PDF in a landscape orientation in Python

Tags: python, excel, pdf

I have this code to save an Excel file as a PDF, but when it saves, it saves as multiple pages with the spreadsheet being cut in half. Is there any possible way to change the orientation to landscape using Python?

```
def PDF():
    
    # Open Microsoft Excel
    excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    
    # Read Excel File
    sheets = excel.Workbooks.Open('Logbook.xlsx')
    work_sheets = sheets.Worksheets[0]
  
    # Convert into PDF File
    work_sheets.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, 'Logbook.pdf')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look up most of this stuff by searching for "excel object model orientation".

```
work_sheets.PageSetup.Orientation = win32com.client.constants.xlLandscape
```

Comment: thanks for your answer however it gave me the following error `AttributeError: xlLandscape`

Comment: Well, it's supposed to bring in all those constants when you use `Dispatch`.  In a pinch, you can say `xlLandscape = 2` and use `xlLandscape` instead of `win32com.client.constants.xlLandscape`.

Comment: that seems like it has worked, thanks a lot!